# How to implement a scroll feature similar to angular.io site

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where I need to have a list on one side of the page and content on another side. On Clicking on any list item, that item will get the active class and its content would be scrolled to top. Also if we scroll the contents then the respective list item should get highlighted. It will be similar to https://angular.io/guide/quickstart, where once we scroll then the active items change while we scroll.

Comment: Your question is too broad and unclear. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular 6.1 you can use

Router Scroller

> The Router Scroller provides functions related to scrolling to the
>   Angular Router. With Router Scroller, you can do the following things.

To implement this check:https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

If you are using angular 5 try ref tgis exmaple:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-scroll-spy-routing